# Reporting on time information using start and end time

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to create a report that sums hours for a day grouped by an Id using a start and end time stamp?

I need to be able to split time that spans days and take part of that time and sum to the correct date group.

NOTE: The date ids are to a date dimension table.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TaskId   | StartDateId | EndDateId | StartTime           | EndTime 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2        | 20190317    | 20190318  | 2019-03-17 16:30:00 | 2019-03-18 09:00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 20190318    | 20190318  | 2019-03-18 09:00:00 | 2019-03-18 16:30:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2        | 20190318    | 20190319  | 2019-03-18 16:30:00 | 2019-03-19 09:00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So based on this, the desired report output would be:

```
-------------------------
Date       | Task | Hours
-------------------------
2019-03-17 | 2    | 7.5
-------------------------
2019-03-18 | 1    | 7.5
-------------------------
2019-03-18 | 2    | 16.5
-------------------------
...
```

The only working solution I have managed to implement is splitting records so that no record spans multiple days. I was hoping to find a report query solution, rather than an ETL base based solution.

Comment: I've seen quite a few questions (and answers) that address this. Its worth doing a site search for your key terms.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dale. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to simulate your problem here: https://rextester.com/DEV45608 and I hope it helps you :) (The CTE GetDates can be replaced by your date dimension)

```
DECLARE @minDate DATE  
DECLARE @maxDate DATE  

CREATE TABLE Tasktime
(
    Task_id INT,
    Start_time DATETIME,
    End_time DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Tasktime VALUES
(2,'2019-03-17 16:30:00','2019-03-18 09:00:00'),
(1,'2019-03-18 09:00:00','2019-03-18 16:30:00'),
(2,'2019-03-18 16:30:00','2019-03-19 09:00:00');

SELECT @mindate = MIN(Start_time) FROM Tasktime;

SELECT @maxdate = MAX(End_time) FROM Tasktime;

;WITH GetDates AS  
(  
SELECT 1 AS counter, @minDate as Date   
UNION ALL  
SELECT counter + 1, DATEADD(day,counter,@minDate)  
from GetDates  
WHERE DATEADD(day, counter, @minDate) <= @maxDate  
)  
SELECT counter, Date INTO #tmp FROM GetDates;

SELECT
g.Date,
t.Task_id,
SUM(
CASE WHEN CAST(t.Start_time AS DATE) = CAST(t.End_time AS DATE) THEN
       DATEDIFF(second, t.Start_time, t.End_time) / 3600.0
     WHEN CAST(t.Start_time AS DATE) = g.Date THEN
       DATEDIFF(second, t.Start_time, CAST(DATEADD(day,1,g.Date) AS DATETIME)) / 3600.0
     WHEN CAST(t.End_time AS DATE) = g.Date THEN
       DATEDIFF(second, CAST(g.Date AS DATETIME), t.End_time) / 3600.0
     ELSE
       24.0
     END) AS hours_on_the_day_for_the_task
from 
#tmp g
INNER JOIN
Tasktime t
ON
g.Date BETWEEN CAST(t.Start_time AS DATE) AND CAST(t.End_time AS DATE)
GROUP BY g.Date, t.Task_id
```

Comment: This is it! I was creating a temp table of seconds and cross joining with that to sum the seconds that joined with the records and was in-between the start and end. Performance was terrible! I didnt know you could put expressions like that inside a SUM function. Thanks

Comment: @DaleBurrell I did mention that I solved it by splitting records so that no record spans multiple days. Made the sum simple. However, I don't think demonstrating solutions that don't work will add value to the question definition.

Comment: @PeteDavis posting unworking attempts absolutely does add value - its the fundamental way SO works, you have a go yourself and then post your unworking code for people to assist you with. Otherwise, regardless of what you say in the question (anyone can say they had a go but it doesn't mean they did), it looks like you're asking people to write the code from scratch for you - and those questions usually get closed.

Answer (score 0):

The Desired Date can be joined to the date dimension and return the "calendar date" and you can show that date in the report.

As for the HOURS.. when you are retrieving your dataset in SQL, just do this.. it is as simple as:

```
 cast(datediff(MINUTE,'2019-03-18 16:30:00','2019-03-19 09:00:00') /60.0 as decimal(13,1)) as 'Hours'
```

So in your case it would be

```
 cast(datediff(MINUTE,sometable.startdate,sometable.enddate) /60.0 as decimal(13,1)) as 'Hours'
```

Just doing a HOUR will return the whole hour.. and dividing by 60 will return a whole number. Hence the /60.0 and the cast

Comment: Probably due to lack of attempt.

Comment: This will get the time between the start and end. However, 7.5 hours of this record is for one date (2019-03-18), and 9 hours is for the next day. And I am trying to report hours on a per day basis.

Comment: Ah.. I didn't get that from your desired result.. glad you found the answer you need.

Comment: Unfortunate example test dataset where the sum and the time difference are identical. It didnt occur to me until I executed your sample. Thanks for your help Harry.